# Working with hStore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, hstore

I have been trying to search my `hstore` but nothing seams to work.

i have a model called `players` with a `hstore` names played_positions

when i do `Player.last`
i get

```
Player.last
#<Player:0x007fa281c04bc8> {
                        :id => 4239,
                :first_name => "Deborah",
                 :last_name => "Rutherford",
                  :nickname => "Eulah",
          :played_positions => {
                                "position" => "OL"
                               }
{
```

but now I am having problems with getting all the players that gave the OL position

in my migration file i have

```
add_column :players, :played_positions, :text
```

And in my model i have

```
 store :played_positions
```

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 2):

This will give you all the players with position `OL`

```
Player.where("played_positions -> 'position' = 'OL'")
```